# Compromissos hora dia Vertical - widget Android

Tags: android

Estou buscando como fazer um widget como da foto mas não encontro uma maneira de fazer e nao encontro uma lib que me ofereça isso. 
Alguem sabe se existe algo nativo ou lib que me ajude?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Penso que é isto que procuras:
[SectionedRecyclerView](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter) com esta lib podes criar um header para cada hora.